# How do you open this light fixture?

Tags: light-bulb

So I have this light fixture in my bathroom whose bulb has blown. And I can't for the life of me figure out how to take this down to change it.
Tried to poke/fiddle with the 3 small openings with a screwdriver, but didn't seem to do anything.
Also tried turning the glass counter clockwise and clockwise with some strength, but didn't seem to budge too.
Any ideas?
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Push pins on the side, I can seeone of them

Comment: Note that just because the switch is off doesn't mean there's no mains power in there. Switch the circuit off at the breaker board if you're going to be poking a screwdriver into it.

Answer (score 3):

Finally managed to open the fixture by turning it really hard clockwise, turns out there was no push pin. The three screws were sitting on an elevated 'latch'.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Don't forget you can mark your own answer as accepted (48 hours after asking the question).

Comment: Of course you can force it open. Still see now how long the push pin has to be too unlock the holding laches. What is the purpose of the insert hole otherwise ??. Forcing it is not the right solution.